# Cross-site scripting (reflected) java-script

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss

please help i have java-script code inside html page and i need to turn off cross-site scripting from inside code not from the browser.

attached an image show the problem i have with XSS

[image]

thanks

Comment: This is not a problem on the client-side. XSS is caused by a server-side coding error. You don’t sanitize your inputs and print the HTML you get on input directly into the page. You have to [edit] your question to show us the server-side code and retag it with the relevant technologies.

Answer (score 0):

The OWASP site has really good information on Cross Site Scripting detection and prevention. In particular you should look at the prevention section in order to attempt to address your problems: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29

There is not enough information in your question for more specific information, but it looks at first glance like the request parameter "city" is having its value injected directly into the page. You would need to ensure that the city parameter does not contain malicious content prior to including it in the page, e.g. by validating it against a white list of acceptable values/characters.

There is more information in best practices in the OWASP link above.